# HTML/CSS Website price table shows colored column with white lines on devices other than laptop

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-table, responsive

I'm trying to make a price list on my website. It's just a simple table like the example code below.

[image]

On my laptop it all looks good but when I view it on another device all of a sudden there appear thin white lines in the gold coloured column.

[image: Image with white lines]

I don't know how they appear and also how to get rid of them any suggestions?

HTML

```
    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="lasronth-th">Gelaat</th>
                            <th class="lasronth-th">Prijs</th>
                            <th class="lasronth-th">Pakketprijs ( 6 + 2 gratis )</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="vrouw-gelaat"
                            data-img="./laserontharing-img/vrouw/gelaat/wenkbrauwen-tussenstuk.png">
                            <td>Wenkbrauwen tussenstuk</td>
                            <td>€ 30</td>
                            <td>€ 180</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="vrouw-gelaat" data-img="./laserontharing-img/vrouw/gelaat/bovenlip.png">
                            <td>Bovenlip</td>
                            <td>€ 35</td>
                            <td>€ 210</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="vrouw-gelaat" data-img="./laserontharing-img/vrouw/gelaat/kin.png">
                            <td>Kin</td>
                            <td>€ 35</td>
                            <td>€ 210</td>
                        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

css :

```
.table-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.laseronth-tbl {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.laseronth-tbl:not(:first-child) {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.laseronth-tbl thead tr th:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

.lasronth-th {
  color: #513f34;
}


.laseronth-tbl tbody tr td:not(:first-child) {
  text-align: center;
}

.laseronth-tbl tbody tr td:nth-child(even) {
  color: #caa463;
  width: 200px;

}

.laseronth-tbl tbody tr td,
.laseronth-tbl thead tr th {
  padding: 8px 0px;
}

.laseronth-tbl tbody tr td:first-child {
  width: 200px;
}

.laseronth-tbl tbody tr td:last-child {
  background-color: #d5b26c;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 250px;
  border:none;
}

.laseronth-tbl tbody tr td {
  color: #513f34;
  width: 74.4680851%;
}
```

Comment: Hi soory I ran your code but It's broken, could you please remove this line .laseronth-tbl:not(:first-child) {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
 and try again?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I removed the lines of code that you suggested, but it still shows it in the same way with the lines in between

Comment: If anyway possible could you share me git repo of your project, I'll take a look for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try `font-size: 0`..

Otherwise the only surefire way is either to overlap the last column backgrounds or to create a background that spans all column rows..

I had this problem.. Came to the conclusion that if you want pixel perfect graphical elements across all devices is to find weird ways.. plus less calculations for the browser if it draws one rectangle instead of many.

Comment: Yeah, I finally found a way, but it's not the pretty kind of code answer. But It works so for now it's fine

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that works for my code.

I gave may table a collapsed border and the coloured column I gave a border of 5px in the colour of the column. That seems to do the trick

```
table{
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td{
border-bottom:5px solid gold
}
```